# Object is possibly 'undefined' in Vue with this.$refs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I switched to typescript and suddenly some of my codes are having errors with:

`Object is possibly 'undefined'`

The typescript version is 3.2.1

Here's the code:

```
this.$refs[`stud-copy-${index}`][0].innerHTML = 'Link Copied'
```

I've tried to add an if condition to check if it's undefined but no luck:

```
if (this.$refs[`stud-copy-${index}`] !== undefined) {
  this.$refs[`stud-copy-${index}`][0].innerHTML = 'Link Copied'
}
```

Comment: what about `if (this.$refs && this.$refs[\`stud-copy-${index}\`] !== undefined) {` - since I think the issue is that it thinks `this.$refs` is possibly undefined

Comment: @Bravo still has the error.

Comment: so, it's not a run time error? i.e. is this error appearing the browser console or somewhere else?

Comment: No, it's not. We use linting and probably it detects an error in the code. It appears when we watch npm.

Comment: so this is a linter setup issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
(this.$refs[`stud-copy-${index}`] as HTMLElement[])[0].innerHTML = 'Link Copied'
```